# To display "venue" in the output of ajax-event-calendar

Tags: wordpress

I searched the "ajax-event-calendar" support forums and FAQ.But, won't got the solution yet.
I want to display the venue details in the output.
[ajax-event-calendar](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/ajax-event-calendar)

Comment: Any help would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I got the solution by myself. Go to plugins folder -> ajax event
   calendar -> ajax-event-calendar.php -> line no. 820

   function render_eventlist_events($events, $whitelabel, $limit) {
       usort($events, array($this, 'array_compare_order'));
       $rows = $this->convert_array_to_object($events); 
       $out = '';
       foreach ($rows as $count => $row) {
       global $wpdb;
       $id1 = $row->id;
       //echo $id1;
           $result1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT venue FROM wp_aec_event WHERE id ='$id1'");
           foreach ( $result1 as $result2 ) { 
               $venue_name = $result2->venue;
           }
           //if ($count < $limit) {
           if (!$limit || $count < $limit) {

   ```
           // split database formatted datetime value into display formatted date and time values
           $row->start_date    = $this->convert_date($row->start, AEC_DB_DATETIME_FORMAT, AEC_WP_DATE_FORMAT);
           $row->start_time    = $this->convert_date($row->start, AEC_DB_DATETIME_FORMAT, AEC_WP_TIME_FORMAT);
           $row->end_date      = $this->convert_date($row->end, AEC_DB_DATETIME_FORMAT, AEC_WP_DATE_FORMAT);
           $row->end_time      = $this->convert_date($row->end, AEC_DB_DATETIME_FORMAT, AEC_WP_TIME_FORMAT);
           // link to event
           $class = ($whitelabel) ? '' : ' ' . $row->className;
           $out .= '<span class="fc-event-time">';
           $out .= $row->start_date;

           if (!$row->allDay) {
               $out .= ' ' . $row->start_time;
           }
           $out .= '</span>';
           $out .= '<div class="fc-event' . $class . '" onClick="jQuery.aecDialog({\'id\':' . $row->id . ',\'start\':\'' . $row->start . '\',\'end\':\'' . $row->end . '\'});">';
           $out .= '<div class="fc-event-title">' . $this->render_i18n_data($row->title) . '</div>';
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
           echo 'if ($(window).width() < 980) {';
               $out .= '<div class="fc-event-mobile">' . $row->start_time . ' | ' . $venue_name . '</div>';
           echo '}';
           echo '</script>';
           $out .= '</div>';
       }
   }
   return $out;
   ```

   }
2. Have to include the code in stars for venue display.